# How to add extra parameter to all queries in Repository

Tags: spring, spring-repositories

I'm letting system to create queries from the methods names:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
Boolean existsByName(String name);
Boolean existsByRegCode(String regCode);
}
```

There are several different repos for different entities (Company, User, Shop) and they all have field named CountryId.

Now I need to add condition "AND CountryId = :CountryId" to all queries in all repos , where the country parameter gets it's value from some configuration file.

I know that I should build some base class for this and extend from that, but can't figure out what to put into this class.

Comment: does Company entity have an association with Country entity?

Comment: Country is just a field in Company table. I update my question

Comment: its a string then? If I understand your question correctly, you could try:
    `Boolean existsByNameAndCountry(String name, String country)`

Comment: Assuming you are using hibernate you can use filters which will be automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a superclass for all of your entities and add the `countryId` field to this superclass and annotate with `@Where(clause = "countryId='id'")`

```
@Where(clause = "countryId='id'")
public class Entity {...}
```

and

```
public class Company extends Entity {...}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this allows only static values: "The problem with @Where annotation is that it allows us to only specify a static query without parameters, and it can’t be disabled or enabled by demand."

Comment: You're right. In case of using hibernate, another way that allows us to change parameters dynamically is AOP, which intercept requests and enable/disable filters based on methods or classes: http://cyriltech.blogspot.com/2017/03/how-to-enable-hibernate-filter-using.html